# I need to make the filter button aligned to the menu and modify its css using bootstrap.I am new to bootstrap so cant figure it out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I  need to make the filter button aligned to the menu and modify its css using bootstrap. I am new to bootstrap so cant figure it out. i have tried padding the result but it didnt work. Thank you in advance :)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav container col-md-6">
    <li class="dropdown col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">School <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
            <li><a href="about_us.php" >About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertise.php">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art Curator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Category <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
            <li><a href="about_us.php" >About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertise.php">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art Curator</a></li>
            <li><a href="work_with_us.php">Jobs & Internships</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Course  <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
            <li><a href="about_us.php" >About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertise.php">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art Curator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Degree  <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
            <li><a href="about_us.php" >About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertise.php">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art Curator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Degree       <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
            <li><a href="about_us.php" >About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertise.php">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art Curator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mine" >Filter Results</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try playing around in the chrome or firefox inspector. You really need to with bootstrap because of all the styling that it adds on top of what you do. You'll need to make sure that you use the full selectors from it to overwrite the bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0):

Add the id **btnFilter** to your "Filter Results" button and add the following css to your stylesheet

```
#btnFilter {
  margin:9px 0 0;
}
.cat > b.caret {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
}
```

The caret on the category dropdown was falling down so I have adjusted that as well by adding class cat and absolutely positioning the caret.
I have created a pen using html you provided. http://codepen.io/shreya1289/pen/KMKOLg

Comment: Your welcome :) can you please mark it as correct answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score -1):

For that you need to some customization for set the control location in your page like as per below it will helpful to you.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .caret{
        margin-left:62px !important;
    }
    a.dropdown-toggle {
        line-height: 0px !important;
    } 
</style>
```

here you are not added full html code so may be you need some alteration in above styles.

Comment: I'm not really sure that this is a valid use of `!important`... Seems like an unnecessary hack to me.

Comment: I am added important because if some style will be conflict. Here not full html so my be conflict style. and one more thing if I am added important so will it be create any issue in the HTML ?

Comment: and answer is not wrong so why down voted the answer?

Comment: Votes aren't about what works, they're about what's the best solution. We use DV's and UV's to help show what is good practice and bad practice. I personally think that using !important is unnecessary in this case and bad practice. Why? You're abusing it's power. If you want to eventually revamp the CSS, it could easily become a pain because you can't overwrite older styles correctly. [`!important` isn't something to be avoided at all costs](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/), but you need a better reason to use it than to overwrite some bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you everyone!